# angular.js template variables to bootbox dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootbox

I've been trying to figure this out for like 10 hours now. Time to ask for help!

I'm trying to pass a variable from an angular.js template variable to bootbox for a nice looking confirmation prompt.

Assume that I have the following (abbreviated for clarity):

```
<script>
      $(document).on("click", ".confirm", (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("This needs to be the value of {{item.name}}", function(confirmed) {
          console.log("Confirmed: "+confirmed);
        });
      }));
</script>
```

which is executed as such:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
         <a href="" class="confirm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire red"></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the user clicks the link, I would like a the confirmation box to appear, and I need to include attributes like {{item.name}} and {{item.row}} that are specific to this element in the list.

I have read up on the $compile functionality of angular.js and I got it working in so far as having a `<div compile="name">` but that doesn't help me for retrieving a single entry out of my list as I am iterating. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of class="confirm", you could use ng-click="functionName(item)", and in the function do your bootbox stuff with the passed in item.

Comment: You might also consider folding everything (markup and JavaScript) into a directive. It could make things much easier to conceptualize and work with as it will fit the AngularJS paradigm better.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the responses. I wound up going with "aet"s simple answer. It never dawned on me that I could invoke the bootbox dialog from within my `function AppCtrl($scope) {...}`. Passing in the item turned out to be a quick and easy solution that worked with 99% of the code I'd already written.

I realize it may not be ideal, but I'm really just working on a little web app for myself. It just needs to function. Nobody but me will be using it.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applied as a directive...

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
         <confirm-button name="{{item.name}}"></confirm-button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: 'one' },
    { name: 'two' },
    { name: 'three' }
  ];
})
.directive('confirmButton', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { name: '@' },
    template: '<a href="#" class="confirm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire red" ng-click="confirm(name)">Button</span></a>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.confirm = function(name) {
        bootbox.confirm("The name from $scope.items for this item is: " + name, function(result){
          if (result) {
            console.log('Confirmed!');
          } else {
            console.log('Cancelled');
          }
        });
      };
    }
  }
});
```

[Working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/RKPyYMFiQMv1NvIgdrvW?p=preview)

Comment: Great answers from everyone. I gave the answer to marck for the working plunk. Thanks to all who took time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach, but depending on what you're trying to do it may not suit you:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        { name: "Bla bla bla bla?", url: "http://stackoverflow.com" },
        { name: "Ble ble ble ble?", url: "http://github.com" }
    ];

    $scope.confirm = function (item) {
        bootbox.confirm("Confirm?", function (confirmed) {
            alert('Confirmed: '+ confirmed +'. Url: '+ item.url);
        });
    };
});
```

In your html:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <a ng-click="confirm(item)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire red"></span> 
                {{ item.name }}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Depending on what you want, maybe you should check out the directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive